# How to get jOOQ code generator to tell me what's wrong?

Tags: java, kotlin, code-generation, jooq

I'm trying to get the jOOQ code generator to do its thing based on my Flyway scripts. Here's my configuration:

```
        GenerationTool.generate(Configuration()
            .withLogging(Logging.TRACE)
            .withOnError(OnError.FAIL)
            .withGenerator(Generator()
                .withDatabase(Database()
                    .withName("org.jooq.meta.extensions.ddl.DDLDatabase")
                    .withIncludes(".*")
                    .withProperties(
                        Property().withKey("scripts").withValue("src/main/resources/db/migration/*.sql"),
                        Property().withKey("sort").withValue("flyway"),
                        Property().withKey("defaultNameCase").withValue("lower")))
                .withGenerate(Generate()
                    .withTables(true)
                    .withPojos(true)
                    .withDaos(true)
                    .withGeneratedAnnotation(true)
                    .withJavaTimeTypes(true)
                    .withRecords(true))
                .withTarget(Target()
                    .withClean(true)
                    .withPackageName("my.package.name")
                    .withDirectory("src/main/java"))
```

(Ignore the missing `new`s, it's Kotlin)

Currently it doesn't seem to be doing anything, including not logging anything. I know the code is executed, but nothing is generated. How do I make it actually log something, so that I have something to go on?

Comment: I just tried to use [the plugin](https://github.com/etiennestuder/gradle-jooq-plugin) instead of a self-defined task, but it has the same exact problem: No output whatsoever.

Comment: When trying your setup locally, everything works as expected, including log output. You'll get best results by adding slf4j and some logging configuration on your classpath. How did you set up your project with Gradle/Maven/other?